# .Net MVC 3 403.14 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating an asp.net MVC3 demo application. I have attached the application with this thread. I'm facing a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden [image]issue when trying to run the application. The issue occurs only in a specific scenario. i.e. in the RegisterRoutes method in the global.asax 
has only the below code then the issue occurs.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Process1", // Route name
                "Process/List" // URL with parameters
            );
```

If we have the above code with default route the application works fine without any issues. The issue occurs when i have this particular code alone in the register routes method. 
I tried the solutions given in this [link](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EWcTV9SvMbPv8weD1KH4Dw#q=http%20error%20403.14%20-%20forbidden%20mvc%203) but it did not work.
I assume the issue with that code. If yes then please let me know what causes the issue. I use windows 8.1 & the iis is 8.5.
The code can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/susur0u419wcan1/DemoMVC3.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the default route and defined the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Process1", // Route name
    "Process/List" // URL with parameters
);
```

In this declaration it is not clear which controller and which action should be 
executed. You should explicitly state them:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Process1", // Route name
    "Process/List", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" }
);
```

and then make sure that you are making the request to the proper url that you have defined:

```
http://localhost:1619/Process/List
```

because you don't have any route configured that is capable of handling the `http://localhost:1619/` request that you seem to have made in your screenshot.

Of course having such route is completely constraining. The only controller action you could ever have in your MVC application is the one defined as such in the route config. This is fine in a SPA application where you have a single entry point serving the SPA and a separate ASP.NET Web API but in a real ASP.NET MVC application with multiple controllers and actions it is not going to work. So you probably want to keep the default route in this case and do not experiment in this area.

Comment: The route routes.MapRoute( "Process1", "Process/List");  works when there is another route preceding to it. The preceding route is routes.MapRoute("Process", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Process", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional });  so here does the routing engine identifies the controller based on the url? if yes why it is not able to identify the controller without the preceding route (as available in the code shared)? Apart from that does the routing engine considers the first route it encounters as the default route or a route that has name as default?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a default root in your global.asax file to make it work. add one default and then you can add this route.

Comment: im unable to understand as why routes.MapRoute("Process1", "Process/List"); is not considered as default route?

Comment: Because you have give its name as Process1, Rename it to default will solve your problem. Mark the answer if it will solve ur issue :)

Comment: I tried but renaming to default also did not solve the issue. I believe the default route is not based on the route name..